# Why do Zener diodes have a lower breakdown voltage than normal?

Tags: diodes, zener, avalanche-breakdown

Here I do not understand some physics.

So for normal diode we have a depletion zone width say **Wn**, and for Zener diode we have **Wz**.

Then, we know that **Wn** > **Wz**. By reverse-biasing we make the depletion zone wider, until **Epn** is too high, and eventually everything breaks, so the current starts flow.

But if **Wz** < **Wn**, than it should have greater **Vbd**?

I assume that the answer is in potential difference between PN. Even though **Wz** < **Wn**,
we have **Ez** >> **En** at PN junction due to higher doping, so it takes much less **Vbd** to start the flow in Zener.

Is it correct?

Comment: Define Vbd please

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode Does the second paragraph help? There are different kinds of breakdown, and low and high voltage Zeners use different kinds with higher voltage Zeners using mechanisms more similar to regular diodes.

Comment: Vbd is the voltage of avalache breakdown

Comment: Let me clarify, there is V of avalanche breakdown, this is similar to nuclear chain reaction, when electrons obtain high kinetic energy and "collide" with others.
For Zener diodes there is also V of Zener breakdown, or Zener effect, resulting in electric field tearing electrons from bonds.
So after Zener BD, if we keep increasing voltage, we get avalanche breakdown, that as for normal diode leads to dying out due to heating up?
Everything correct?

Comment: Note that you only see actual Zener breakdown making any significant contribution in diodes with a breakdown voltage of less than about 6 V; most Zener diodes primarily undergo avalanche breakdown, just like conventional diodes. They just have a precisely controlled breakdown voltage.

Comment: SO theoretically its possible for normal diode to have a zener effect, but it lies beyond avalanche BD voltage and unachivable

Comment: No @Roman see my answer

Comment: @Roman if Zener breakdown occurs at all in normal diodes (I suspect it would, if the diode was bad enough, as there's nothing really special about a zener in terms of its construction), it's a negligible contribution to the breakdown current, since most conventional diodes break down at hundreds of volts. I don't know if zener breakdown can occur in Schottky diodes.

Comment: @MissMulan I mean possibility is not 0, in practice its impossible because of too large depletion zone

Comment: @Roman Rather than attempt something better read from the sources, I'd recommend that you read (Zener was a true genius physicist, quiet and very generous in dishing out credit to those who worked with him) this paper: *"A Theory of the Electrical Breakdown of Solid Dielectrics,"* by C Zener, revised 1 Mar 1934. It's available from the Proceedings of the Royal Society. Also, read *"Zener Tunneling in Semiconductors,"* by E. O. Kane, revised 24 Jul 1959. I feel these two are all that's really needed to understand the effect. When asking such questions, it is usually better to go to the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zener breakdown in zener diodes is due to quantum tunneling.The doping of a zener diode is very big-> the electric field is very big -> the width of the depletion region is very small and **doesnt change with applied reverse voltages**.

Now back to quantum tunneling:

As shown in the picture a classical particle cannot go from the first bottom of the hill to the second bottom of the hill without giving the particle some energy to overcome the potential energy needed to reach the top of the hill then roll back down.

[image]

However quantum particles(electrons or holes) can tunnel through the the hill as long as the hill is very small in width and has a finite potential at the top of the hill.

In our case at the zener breakdown voltage the energy of the conduction electrons in  n type region becomes equal to the energy of the valence holes in the p type region and because the barrier is very small in width and the electric field of the depletion region is of finite value electrons from the conduction band of n type region can tunnel to the valence band of the p type region.

Note however we have a second breakdown voltage called the avalanche breakdown voltage under which the kinetic energy of the minority charge carriers inside the depletion region can break the bond of a atom with its valence electron creating a electron-hole pair increasing current tremendously and destorying the diode.The avalance breakdown voltage is much higher than the zener breakdown voltage.

Normal diodes exhibit only avalanche breakdown while zener diodes exhibit both zener and avalanche breakdown.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt see any word about tunneling as mechanic of zener effect

Comment: Quantum tunneling is mentioned in the Wikipedia page on the Zener effect.

Comment: Note that "Zener diodes" almost always work by a combination of Zener tunneling and avalanche breakdown, with Zener tunneling dominating at lower voltages and avalanche breakdown dominating at higher voltages.